# How do I add text in a cell based on information from a separate cell in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Column A is a list of city names, and I want to add a column B for a list of the counties that correspond to the cities.  Example: Charlotte Hall, Piney Point, and Lexington Park are all located in St. Mary's county; Waldorf, La Plata, and Nanjemoy are all located in Charles County. How can I create a conditional formula so that for every city in column A, I have the correct county in column B?

Comment: probably you'll need to use `VLOOKUP`,  but without knowing more details on your data's structure it's not possible to help more.

Comment: Thank you for responding Mate. I have a simple excel spreadsheet with about 5 columns: organization name, address, city, state, and zip.

Answer (score 0):

Place a lookup table in say columns **E** and **F**, then in **B1** enter the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E$1:F$565,2)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

Note:

The cities are in **alphabetic order**.